# Jumping knights on a 4x4 grid

Tags: chess

Two players (black and white) alternate in making moves. Each turn a player must use one of his knights to capture an opponent's knight. Knights use standard chess moves. It is black's turn in the following starting configuration. Can the players work together to obtain a single knight on the grid?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> !. ... Nd1xc3 2.Na4xc3 Nc4xd2 3.Na3xb1 Nd2xb1 4.Nb3xc1 Nb1xc3 5.Nc1xa2 Nc3xa2

therefore

> yes, it is possible.

Comment: Nice work. I guess that was too easy. I need to make a harder version for you.