# Jumping knights on a 5x5 grid

Tags: chess

Two players (black and white) alternate in making moves. Each turn a player must use one of his knights to capture an opponent's knight. Knights use standard chess moves. It is black's turn in the following starting configuration. Can the players work together to obtain a single knight on the grid?

[image]

Here is a simpler 4x4 version of this puzzle: [Jumping knights on a 4x4 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114758/jumping-knights-on-a-4x4-grid)

Comment: Hmmm perhaps this puzzle is too hard? I am glad I didn't provide the version where every cell had a knight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, like this

> [image]

Solved by computer (hand written C code).

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: One of 945898 solutions.

Comment: Wow so many solutions!

Comment: Could you provide your code too?

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/wavering-dot/puzzling-114768/blob/main/SO-114768d.c).